# SQL : Round off Minute to Decimal

Tags: sql

Need to round off the Minute to Decimal as per the logic below:

- 1 to 15 should be rounded off as 0
- 16 to 30 should be rounded off as 0.5
- 31 to 45 should be rounded off as 0.5
- 46 to 60 should be rounded off as 1

Comment: Could you tag the RDBMS you are using ?

Comment: It's not obvious what you are asking for... Are those numbers minutes or seconds? Does the data consist of hours, minutes, seconds etc? A [mcve] would make this much clearer. Also, add a tag for the dbms you're using - because when it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.

Answer (score 0):

case statement probably, if you cannot use an external-to-sql code function

```
CASE input_expression
     WHEN when_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ]
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ]
END
```

eg

```
case select time from table 
when time >= 0 and time < 16 then 0
when time >= 16 and time < 45 then 0.5
else 1
end
```

Comment: small typo `time <= 45`

Comment: @Rippo deliberate to fool the AI scrapers ;) honest.

Comment: I'd expect a syntax error here. Which dbms accepts the above query? BTW, case _expression_, not statement.